# Recovering data from TrueNAS pool in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, data-recovery, truenas

I am having a heck of a time trying to get my data off my drives that were in a pool in TrueNAS. I installed Ubuntu on another drive in the same server and loaded Ubuntu 21.04 and installed zfsutils. I was able to import the pool and finally figure out how to mount the vdevs,kinda, and see the data. Right now it is resilvering, but it is taking forever. It is in a degraded state. A drive had failed out of no where after I replaced another drive. This drive wasn't previously showing any issues or errors before. That is when it all start with the I/O errors and all. I have been working on this for days, trying to get the files off the pool. The one failed drive listed in the pic, I can't remove it. I would also like to try and speed up the resilvering if possible. I had a backup of all this data, but it was temporarily wiped due to moving over to another system. I know, stupid mistake, but I wasn't expecting the drive that showed no errors or symptoms of being bad, to actually fail on me out of nowhere.

So back to recovering the data. I can browse the pool and dataset and see the data, but when I try to copy over the files, I get an I/O error and it won't copy. Can anyone please help me figure this out? Even if I need to do an actual data recovery, that is fine, I just don't want to lose 88tb worth of data. Please forgive me ahead of time, I am not a Linux guy, I come from a Windows and Mac background. Everyone talked about TrueNAS/FreeNAS and thought I would give it a shot, but I've had nothing but trouble out of it since I set it up. I've replaced 8 drives so far and they might not have actually been bad, except this one drive. I know ZFS is supposed to be solid, but since I don't know Linux, maybe I'm just not understanding how to go about recovering the data back properly.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDONf.jpg) is the errors that I'm seeing. The last pic shows the unavailable drive that is currently removed out of the system.

Comment: You may need a [ZFS consultant](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite?tab=profile) to assist. Is this for personal use or business?

Comment: This is for personal.

Answer (score 0):

I would not have used a Linux system for a FreeBSD zpool (because this is TrueNAS, a BSD system and has nothing to do with Linux)

" I would also like to try and speed up the resilvering if possible "

In fact, no, or rather, it depends on the version of zfs you are using.
The more modern ones have (by themselves, you don't have to do anything) a more advanced, sequential resilvering, which improves times, especially for almost full volumes.

It is an openzfs technology, essentially an attempt to merge zfs development on BSD with Linux.
In the case of BSD it is active since version 13 (and, personally, I do not find it particularly reliable)

Back to the question: I suppose you are done by now, or do you need further support?